# analyze algorithm of finding maximum number in array with n number

Tags: algorithm

```
def maximum(array):
  max = array[0]
  counter = 0

  for i in array:
      size +=1
      if i>max:
          max=i

  return max
```

I need to analyze that algorithm which find maximum number in array with n numbers in it. the only thing I want to know how to get Recursive and General formula for Average case of this algorithm.

Comment: The average, best, and worst case are all the same since the algorithm looks at each and every element once, no matter what. There isn't much to analize. Also a not on using `max`: it's a built-in function in python, so you better avoid shadowing it.

Comment: max() is a built-in function if you would take a look you would realize that max is just variable which is equal to first element of array...

Comment: That what I'm saying. `max` in your code is initialized with the first element in the array and tracks the largest so far. This overwrites the built-in `max` function. It is syntactically correct and works just fine for your code, but it's best practice to not do that. It makes your code less readable/maintanable.

Comment: @BMW BOI, Will you agree, if the solution will be in C++?

Comment: @BMWBOI: Not sure why you do `size +=1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "Recursive and General formula for Average case of this algorithm". Your algorithm is not recursive. So, how can it be "recursive formula"?

**Recursive way to find maximum in an array:**

```
def findMax(Array, n):
    if (n == 1):
        return A[0]
    return max(Array[n - 1], findMax(Array, n - 1))
```

I guess you want [Recurrence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation).

Let `T(n)` be time taken to find the maximum of `n` elements. So, for above written code.

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + 1 .... Equation I
```

**In case you are interested to solve the recurrence relation:**

```
T(n-1) = T((n-1)-1) + 1 = T(n-2) + 1 .... Equation II
```

If you substitute value of `T(n-1)` from Equation II into Equation I, you get:

```
T(n) = (T(n-2) + 1) + 1 = T(n-2) + 2
```

Similarly,

```
T(n) = T(n-3) + 3
T(n) = T(n-4) + 4
```

and so on..

Continuing the above for `k` times,

```
T(n) = T(n-k) + k
```

If n-k = 0, means n = k. The equation then becomes

```
T(n) = T(0) + n = 1 + n
```

Therefore, the recursive algorithm we came up with has **time complexity `O(n)`**.

Hope it helped.